# Android emulator in azure vm won't start

Tags: android, azure, android-emulator

I am using a nested virtualization with azure vm Standard D4ds v4 Gen 1, this enables it.
On Windows Server 2019 Datacenter

I already installed haxm, different version, and activated or deactived Hypervisorplatform.

Currently I am trying to start a android emulator which I installed through Visual studio. API 30

It just shortly starts and immediately closes.

```
Sc query intelhaxm
```

tells me it is running

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator-check.exe" accel
```

tells me haxm is available

the vulkan.dll file is in the directory in the log

Weird is, that 3 months ago I actually got it to work on some other server, and now it doesn't work anymore.

Somebody has tried something different and it worked?

I already tried starting through command console with and without following tags

```
-partition-size 512 -feature -Vulkan
```

I already created an advancedFeatures.ini with following content

```
Vulkan = off
GLDirectMem = on
```

Currently at the first start, following info is shown

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\2\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
INFO    | IPv4 server found: 10.224.255.5
WARNING | Your GPU drivers may have a bug. Switching to software rendering.
WARNING | cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
WARNING | cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
INFO    | added library C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64\vulkan\vulkan-1.dll
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
dsound: Could not initialize DirectSound
dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID
Could not init `dsound' audio driver
WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: none
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\6008 for reading.
INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\adm_wieser0\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_6384.ini
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\6008 for reading.
INFO    | Setting display: 0 configuration to: 1080x1920, dpi: 420x420
VCPU shutdown request
VCPU shutdown request
```

After the second start, it changes a little bit.

```
INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.14.0 (build_id 10330179) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-30\google_apis_playstore\x86\
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: C:\Users\adm_wieser0\AppData\Local\Temp\2\\AndroidEmulator\emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
INFO    | IPv4 server found: 10.224.255.5
WARNING | Your GPU drivers may have a bug. Switching to software rendering.
WARNING | cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
WARNING | cannot add library vulkan-1.dll: failed
INFO    | added library C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\lib64\vulkan\vulkan-1.dll
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
dsound: Could not initialize DirectSound
dsound: Reason: No sound driver is available for use, or the given GUID is not a valid DirectSound device ID
Could not init `dsound' audio driver
WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: none
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\adm_wieser0\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\6008 for reading.
INFO    | Advertising in: C:\Users\adm_wieser0\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\pid_6096.ini
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\adm_wieser0\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\6008 for reading.
INFO    | Setting display: 0 configuration to: 1080x1920, dpi: 420x420
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\adm_wieser0\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\6008 for reading.
ERROR   | The emulator hardware cannot load snapshot: default_boot
VCPU shutdown request
VCPU shutdown request
WARNING | Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\adm_wieser0\AppData\Local\Temp\avd\running\6008 for reading.
```